React Component gets rerendered
I have a React wrapper component which gets re-rendered. This is actually related to a wrapper for a microfrontend.
How can I find out what causes it to suddenly re-render even though the control is now in the child MFE and this wrapper is actually in the parent app ?
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('myMfe/MyComponent'))
const MyComponentWrapper = (props)=>{
  console.log("props",props);
  return(
    <div>
      <React.Suspense  fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <MyComponent {...props}/>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
};

export default MyComponentWrapper;

High-level flow is as below;
Parent (App.js) has some Route mappings  as below;
<Route exact path="/Path1">
     <MyComponentWrapper url={user} />
</Route>

Then I have the above wrapper i.e. MyComponentWrapper
Then comes the child App's where I have the same route mapping, but in the child App route mapping, it resolves to the actual component to be rendered on screen as below
<Route exact path="/Path1">
     <MyChildComponent />
</Route>

UPDATE
I tried to prevent re-render by using React.memo...But even after that, the component is still re-rendering. Again, the parent of this i.e. the App component does not re-render, only this one
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('myMfe/MyComponent'))
const MyComponentWrapper = React.memo((props)=>{
  console.log("props",props);
  return(
    <div>
      <React.Suspense  fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <MyComponent {...props}/>
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
});

export default MyComponentWrapper;


It's probably rerendering because its parent rerendered. Step up the chain of components to figure out which one is starting the render.

yeah....surprisingly the parent is App.js and I do not get the breakpoint stop in App.js

Does this component get rerendered just one time, or repeatedly?

It re-renders just once

I have updated the question with high-level flow what I have

It re-renders just once are you using <StrictMode>?

I am not using StrictMode

You should use the React Profiler to check what's causing the re-render

Assuming this is a simplified form of your actual implementation, what kinds of state does the re-rendered component consume? Does it have an "isLoading" state, subscribe to a redux selector, listening to a context provider? Those might be the culprit.

Add a console.log statement inside the wrapper component to log the props and see if they change between renders.
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = React.memo((props) => {
  // Component logic using props
}, () => true);

export default MyComponent;


Thanks...and in case, I do not want the rerender when say I am already  in my child app...can I do something about it?

you can use react.memo to stop the re rendering. oh your child component.

Yeah right....even i was thinking the same....is there any variation that I need to try with memo or simply wrap my MyComponentWrapper with React.memo() and that should work ?

Actually, I just tried wrapping with React.memo....it still re-renders !!

Pls see UPDATED in original question to see what I tried

Is you props are changing? If so, then the React.memo can't stop re-rending.
Even if you props are changing and you don't want to re-render you component.  You can use like this.
import React from 'react';
const MyComponent = React.memo((props) => {
// Component logic using props
}, () => true);
export default MyComponent;
